# Why placing a call programatically gives error message "Internet Calling not Supported"?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

This is my code:

```
public String a_number;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_the_call);

    //
    callButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.call_button);
    aCall = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number_a);

    a_number = aCall.getText().toString();
}

public void makeCallFunction(View view) {
        String temp = "";
        temp = "tel:"+a_number;
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(temp));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
```

My XML file contains:

```
        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/call_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dial"
        android:onClick="makeCallFunction"/>
```

I have added the following in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

I searched my best for answers but found nothing helpful..

EDIT:

When I give a value directly, the call gets placed now.
Eg:

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9876543210"));
```

But the problem remains when I read the number from my text view and try to place call with that number.

Can someone help me out?
Thanks in advance

If there's some alternate way to implement call, that'd help too.

Comment: The message is related to using Wi-Fi to make phone calls.  I don't have that feature on my phone, so I can only guess about what you need to do.  Try opening the phone app, then use the menu to go to Settings, and look for something labeled "SIP" or "Wi-Fi Calling".  When you find that, disable it and run your code again.

Comment: I searched for this option, didn't find it. Anyway, I tried turning Wi-Fi off and calling but got the same result..

Comment: I just got the same error. in my case phone number was mapped to a string resource, so I used `@string/some_number` instead of the number itself. You have not specified the XML for `R.id.number_a`, but if it is mapped, e.g. contains `@string/some_number`, you must replace `a_number = aCall.getText().toString()` with `a_number = getString(aCall.getText().toString())`

Answer (score 0):

Disable SIP Internet Calling and VoIP on your emulator or debugging device. This is the steps for Samsung Galaxy S4 :

> go to settings > call > disable internet calling(in bottom)

I don't know what you are doing wrong, but see for yourself a working example :
**MakeTheCallActivity.java**

```
package com.example.makethecall;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MakeTheCallActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText mEditText;
private Button mButton;
private final String TAG = "MakeTheCallActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_the_call);

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.call_button);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            String phoneNumber = mEditText.getText().toString();
            Log.d(TAG, phoneNumber);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**activity_make_the_call.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MakeTheCallActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/phone_number" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="call"
    android:id="@+id/call_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sauravsamamt.makethecall" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MakeTheCallActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

You can see I'm not using a hardcoded number. Make sure you enter a valid number. That's it.

Comment: Actually, most of the slightly-related answers suggested disabling Internet calling..
Also, I don't have this option on my phone.. :(

Comment: Oh! now I look your code. My bad. I guess you're trying to place a normal call...right?

Comment: Yep.. by service provider

Comment: checkout the edited answer...You have not paste your full code so its hard to see what's the problem...but for your sake here is working example, tested using usb debugged android phone.

Comment: First of all, Thanku so much for your time and help :) ... My code is very similar except that I've got two TextView s instead of EditText and an ImageButton to make the call. I'll edit my post to make that clear. Anyway, I'm getting the same problem still.. :(

Comment: are you typecasting your fetched number to String before using it to call ?numberTextView.getText().toString()

Comment: a_number = aCall.getText().toString();
b_number = bCall.getText().toString();

Yes..

Comment: try logging the Uri.parse(temp) or temp before starting the intent...see whats in log! Also post whole error stacktrace here